# ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'FirebaseAuth': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

> ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'FirebaseAuth': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported. No frame with index 29..

I don't know what's wrong with my code, I have used password auth on mobile apps before and it worked perfectly fine, but now idk what's wrong with my web app, tried everything, firebase is initialised everywhere in index.html, main.dart, with all the keys and ids and so is Firebase Auth but I can't figure it out.

[image]

```
// ignore_for_file: camel_case_types, unused_local_variable

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

import '../widgets/neubox.dart';
import '../widgets/textfield.dart';

class login_page extends StatefulWidget {
  const login_page({super.key});

  @override
  State<login_page> createState() => _login_pageState();
}

class _login_pageState extends State<login_page> {
  bool _loading = false;
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode f1 = FocusNode();
  FocusNode f2 = FocusNode();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Future signIn() async {
    print("sigining in");

    final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _emailController.text.trim(),
        password: _passwordController.text.trim());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 150,
                  width: 150,
                  child: Image.asset(
                      "/Users/mustafakhetran/flutterdev/pakcarriagecompany/assets/images/PCC.png"),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Center(
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 400,
                      width: 400,
                      child: NeuBox(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Login",
                              style: GoogleFonts.alef(
                                  fontSize: 50, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 30,
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                height: 80,
                                child: InputFeild(
                                  label: "Email",
                                  focusnode: f1,
                                  feildsubmit: f2,
                                  controller: _emailController,
                                  validator: "Enter Email",
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                height: 80,
                                child: InputFeild(
                                  label: "Password",
                                  focusnode: f2,
                                  keyboardtype: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                                  validator: "Enter Password",
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 60,
                              width: 300,
                              child: FloatingActionButton(
                                shape: const BeveledRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(12),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
                                onPressed: signIn,
                                child: _loading
                                    ? const CircularProgressIndicator(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        strokeWidth: 5,
                                      )
                                    : Text(
                                        "Login",
                                        style: GoogleFonts.adventPro(
                                            fontSize: 30,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```